# How to run script which start kubernetes cluster on azure devops

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I tried to start #kubernetes cluster and then run tests and publish results. Do you have any idea on how this can be done?

1. I created a pipeline but I do not know which yml to use
2. Which task to add first - kubernetes deploy or something else

Comment: I have yml file with all services which need should i upload it and how

Answer (score 0):

We have Kubernetes deployment.yml file>>It takes the container( image )(exampleacr.io/sampleapp) that we going to publish on AKS
App version: app/v1

Service.yml  is to just expose the application  App version: v1

Both the yml files are to be added .Please refer WAY2 for modifying manually.

[image]

**WAY 1:**

Quick way: `Deploy to Azure Kubernetes service` will do everything that’s needed because if you use the [Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/aks-template?view=azure-devops) template, these variables get defined for you.

Steps:

1. Create AKS cluster and ACR(container registry) in azure.
2. In azure Devops:

   Create a pipeline>choose any source:for  select an application
   hosted in git hub
3. Then select Deploy to Azure Kubernetes service >select your aks
   subscription> select the existing  cluster>then select the container
   registry that you want to put docker image into.keep the remaining
   as default
4. Click on validate and configure

azure pipeline will generate a YAML file.

5. In the review pipeline YAML of azure-pipelines.yml

You have two stages:Build,deploy

Click save and run:This saves yaml file in master branch and  it creates manifests files(deployment.yml and service.yml) for kubernetes deployment.

6. Click save and run>this  will also trigger build.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-kubernetes?view=azure-devops)

**WAY2:** Using Docker image

1. To do modifications in the azurepipelines.yml file In the 3rd step from above ,Select Docker image  instead of Deploy to Azure Kubernetes service.
2. Under configure pipeline>If it is in Build.SourcesDirectory in our
   application , it will appear as say $
   Build.SourcesDirectory/app/Dockerfile

That builds the docker file /pipeline.

3. In the review pipeline YAML of azure-pipelines.yml

   Few things can be modified like
4. You can change variable tag to repo name: and then deployment and
   service.yml file can be added to the yml file by doing few
   modifications

Build stage is automatic and no need to modify there.

You have to Add push and deploy stages  in yml file as shown in the [article](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/deploy-to-azure-kubernetes-aks-from-azure-devops-with-azure-pipelines-37b2)

And get source code [here](https://github.com/n3wt0n/Deploy-to-AKS)